# find a subset of numbers that most closely match a sum

Tags: linux, set, subset

I'm looking for a technique or algorithm that will give me a subset of integers from a given set that, when summed, most closely match a given target number.

I have a music video and I want video for 248 frames. I have a set of clips of various lengths, all less than 248. I would like a subset of those that are closest to 248 when their lengths are summed.

Is there something on the linux command line that I can use to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ye Olde [Bin Packing Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and oddly I can't think of a standard implementation.